# Latex margins, need specific advice for publishing specifications

Tags: margins

My university requires that my thesis have specific margins:

> the margin on the binding edge of the page, i.e. the left-hand edge of
>   a recto and the right-hand edge of a verso, shall be not less than
>   40mm. Other margins shall be not less than 15mm

Is there any way to make the left margin on the front of a page and the right margin on the back to be bigger?

I read [here](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907057) that the margins for 12 pt, which I am using, have 1.5 inch margins which is only about 38mm.  I would need to make sure that it was at least 40, but only on those specific sides.  In addition, I am using A4 paper which has slightly different dimensions than regular US paper.  I already have the pdf set up for A4, but I need to adjust the margins.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify a binding offset to `geometry`

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=25mm,
  heightrounded,
}
```

If you want wider margins, adjust the binding offset. However, a binding offset of 25mm (as requested) is justified only for ring binding or similar method. Universities have very bizarre requirements.