# customs margins of my paper

Tags: margins, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latex margins, need specific advice for publishing specifications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62162/latex-margins-need-specific-advice-for-publishing-specifications)

I'm trying to set the margins of my paper using `geometry`. I would set the margin of binding `3.5cm` instead the others `3.0cm`. The geometry package is hard to use.How can I resolve?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\usepackage[margin=3cm,bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

and add the option `twoside` to `\documentclass{<class>}` if you're publishing in `twoside` mode.